# String vs. large INT

Tags: database, string, integer

I'm planning on a web app with a database in the background having big numbers stored. I'm thinking of if it could be possible, that integers need more space than storing the same number as a string.

So normally an integer is stored by base 2 numbers:

> That means for 0 and 1 I need 1 bit while I would need 8 bit to write
>   them as a char.
>
> Writing 2 I would need 2 bit but still 8 bit as char.

Is there something like a break even point therefor. If so, at what number is it?

Thanks so far.

Comment: `100010001`  needs 9 bytes as a string, but just two bytes as an integer (at least in all relational databases I know).

Comment: An unsigned 8-bit integer can represent 256 values using a single byte, which would require up to 3 bytes to represent as a string. Integers require _less_ space than strings.

Answer (score 3):

Optimizing bitwise operations is not anything that people using databases do (with perhaps some minor exceptions).

You are using the database for its ACID properties, and perhaps for its ability to query and manage data. You are using it because it scales easily, manages multiple processors, manages multiple disks, and manages memory hierarchies. You are not using it because it stores the data in the smallest amount of space.

You should worry about other aspects of your application and the data model you want to use.